# Put a Line art modifier on an object behind a grease pencil object

Tags: modeling, workflow, grease-pencil, lineart

I put a 3D object behind a grease pencil canvas, but when I use the line art modifier the line appears over my drawing. Is there a way to put the line art modifier behind the grease pencil canvas?

[image: exemple of what i get]

Answer (score 0):

In the GP object properties (green squiggle icon), in the `Strokes` section, select `3D Location` for Stroke Depth Order